socket.io not working correctly with Next.js custom server in production
I'm currently using a custom server with Next.js and also using the socket.io server. It works fine locally, but I keep getting errors in the production environment (404 not found error).
According to the official documentation, when I make a request like this:
curl "${server_url}/socket.io/?EIO=4%transport=polling"
it should return a response like this if everything is set up correctly.:
{"sid":"o2vq6wpNOe8n3CUVAAAC","upgrades : ["websocket"], "pingInterval":25000, "pingTimeout":20000," maxPayload":1000000}
However, I keep getting the HTML file for that path instead.
Here are my Next.js and socket.io configuration files:
server.js (custom server)
import {createServer} from 'node:http';
import next from 'next';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3030;

const app = next({dev, hostname, port});

const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const httpServer = createServer(handler);

  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    },
  });
  io.on('connection', async socket => {

  });

  httpServer
    .once('error', err => {
      console.error(err, '?');
      process.exit(1);
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
    });
});

next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  output : "standalone",
  reactStrictMode: false,
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },

  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    loaderFile: './src/@utils/imageLoader/loader.ts',
  },
};


export default nextConfig;

socket.js
'use client';

import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io();

page.tsx (where i connect to server)
'use client';

import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Spinner from '@_components/organisms/Spinner';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import {memo} from 'react';
import {socket} from '@_utils/socketClient';
import './game.scss';

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('@_components/organisms/Game'),
  {
    ssr: false,
  },
);

export default function RealGame() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [transport, setTransport] = useState('N/A');

  useEffect(() => {
    const observeGame = () => {
      const targetNode = document.getElementById('kmabl-game')!;

      const config = {childList: true};

      const callback = (
        mutationsList: MutationRecord[],
        observer: MutationObserver,
      ) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            observer.disconnect();
          }
        }
      };

      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

      observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    };

    const onConnect = () => {
      setIsConnected(true);
      setTransport(socket.io.engine.transport.name);

      socket.io.engine.on('upgrade', transport => {
        setTransport(transport.name);
      });
    };

    const onDisconnect = () => {
      setIsConnected(false);
      setTransport('N/A');
    };

    observeGame();

    if (socket.connected) {
      onConnect();
    }

    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
    socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);

    return () => {
      socket.off('connect', onConnect);
      socket.off('disconnect', onDisconnect);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(isConnected, transport);

  return (
    <>
      <Spinner isLoaded={isLoaded} />
      <GameComponent />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
    </>
  );
}

const GameComponent = memo(() => {
  return <div id="kmabl-game"></div>;
});

GameComponent.displayName = 'GameComponent';

So I removed the  output: standalone option in next.config.mjs, and it started working correctly.
Currently, I have a post-build step that forcibly pushes the static files built with standalone mode back to the Next.js server.
It seems to be related to that. Does this mean socket.io cannot be used in standalone mode?
